# Помогите понять утверждение: "перед вызовом метода не проверяется, есть ли такой метод у объекта или нет. Все проверки происходят во время выполнения"

Tags: java, ооп, методы

> В Java **перед вызовом метода не проверяется, есть ли такой метод у объекта или нет. Все проверки происходят во время выполнения.** И [гипотетический] вызов отсутствующего метода, скорее всего, приведет к тому, что программа начнет выполнять байт-код там, где его нет. Это, в конце концов, приведет к фатальной ошибке, и операционная система принудительно закроет программу.

```java
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass some = new SomeClass();

        some.someMethod(); // <- Cannot resolve method 'someMethod' in 'SomeClass'
    }
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, что подразумевается в данном абзаце? Ведь если попытаться вызвать у объекта несуществующий метод, то уже до компиляции об этом будет просигнализировано. Равно как и на этапе компиляции, без участия IDEA, возникнет ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По большей части то, что написано в том абзаце, неверно. Самое главное, в чем там ошибка, тут:

> вызов отсутствующего метода, скорее всего, приведет к тому, что программа начнет выполнять байт-код там, где его нет. Это, в конце концов, приведет к фатальной ошибке, и операционная система принудительно закроет программу.

То что может возникнуть ситуация, когда один класс пробует вызвать у другого несуществующий метод, это правда (смотрите далее пример, как именно это может случится учитывая, что java компилируемый и строго типизируемый язык).

Но в таком случае не будет никакого выполнения "байт-кода там, где его нет", и уж тем более операционная система не будет принудительно закрывать программу.

Всего лишь будет брошено исключение `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` и программа даже может это исключение обработать, если есть необходимость, или, если это был главный поток, то программа завершиться так же (т.е. штатным образом), как программа завершается при возникновении любого необработанного исключения.

Когда может возникнуть ситуация, что необходимо исключение обрабатывать? Обычно это делать не нужно, но иногда, например, если у вас программа - контейнер сервлетов, и в нее динамически загружаются веб приложения. Тогда при возникновении исключения при старте веб приложения, ваша программа, которая по сути является контейнером, не должна завершаться с ошибкой, а вместо этого должна все необработанные исключения возникшие в веб приложениях отлавливать, куда-то о них сообщать (в простом случае это может быть просто запись в журнал) и продолжать дальше работать.

Обычному же приложению такого рода ошибку обрабатывать смысла нет. Она возникает из-за проблем с конфигурацией приложения. Сейчас опишу как она может возникнуть в принципе.

Допустим у вас есть класс `A` в библиотеке `Lib1`, которую разрабатываете вы:

```
class A {
   int f() {
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Вы выпустили версию библиотеки 1 и теперь используете (или кто-то другой использует) ее в своей программе, а именно в классе `B`:

```
class B {
    void g() {
        A a = A();
        System.out.println(a.f());
    }
}
```

Скомпилировали, все работает - все нормально.

А теперь, вы вносите изменения в библиотеку `Lib1`, а именно меняете сигнатуру функции `f` (или вообще удаляете эту функцию):

```
class A {
   int f(int x) {
       return x + 1;
   }
}
```

И выпускаете версию 2 своей библиотеки.
Если теперь запустить программу с классом `B` без ее перекомпиляции, но с использованием новой версии библиотеки, то возникнет ошибка, что метод `f()` не найден в классе `A`.

В скомпилированном коде класса `B` есть вызов метода из класса `A` c сигнатурой `int f()`. И если такого метода нет, то в момент вызова среда (т.е. JVM) бросает исключение `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

Может возникнуть вопрос, почему не делать строгую проверку, что класс `A` при втором запуске, это не тот же класс `A`, который использовался во время компиляции?

Такое решение имеет ряд недостатков, чтоб все их описать это нужно целую статью писать, но один из важных, это трудности с обновлением библиотек. Текущее решения позволяет обновить библиотеки без перекомпиляции всех зависимостей (т.е. обновить Lib1 без перекомпиляции `B` и его клиентов), если API библиотеки не менялось. Для этого используется [версионирование](https://habr.com/ru/company/Voximplant/blog/281593/).

Answer (score 2):

Эта фраза (которая взята [отсюда](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questcore.level05.lecture01)) выдернута из контекста. Попробуйте запустить тот код, который предложил автор статьи и вы убедитесь, что там вылетит ошибка. А тот код, который вы привели не запустится (Java не даст этого сделать из-за строгой типизации).

А вообще, я советую не париться о таких мелочах на начальном этапе (за 2 года, мне не разу не встретилось такое поведение в джаве). Кому-кому, а новичку вообще не надо переживать о таких "выкрутасах" языка. Достаточно просто знать какие есть типы модификаторов и когда их применять.

Comment: Руслан, выполнение – это RunTime, верно? Тогда как ошибка в коде из статьи возникнет на этапе building.

Comment: @Rostik `Runtime` - промежуток времени, когда выполняется программа. Ошибки в рантайме намного хуже, чем ошибки на этапе копиляции (то, что вы сказали building), потому что после их выпадения программисту требуется понять что случилось (когда программа достаточно большая, сделать это совсем не просто). Когда же ошибка вылетает на этапе компиляции, программисту сразу же понятно, что и где не так работает.

Answer (score 0):

Какой абзац вас удивляет? Возможен ли вариант, что в неком классе не будет некоего метода, а в другом классе попытаются обратиться к методу первого класса, да такое  возможно и такое сплошь и рядом. особенно когда команда разработчиков большая.
Класс с отсутствующим методом либо скомпилируется успешно, если в само классе нет  обращения к этому методу,либо не будет скомпилирован, если присутствует обращение к  не существующему методу.
Но проект содержащий много классов будет собран и вероятно даже сможет работать .